# UIViewController background collor below view

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uianimation

Here's my issue. I have a UIViewController with a custom view as it's view(controller.view = custom). I also add some more views to the controller as subviews of it's view. Now after this view appears, so in the viewDidApear I add an bounce animation. The problem is that for the bounce animation i change the controllers view origin from 0 to 20 and in that space I get the black background. Is there a way to change that background to a collor of my choosing?

Comment: try to set the background color of controller on the interface boulder to "clear color"

Answer (score 0):

Your better option is to not animate the full view but to use the controllers view as a container for another view that holds everything and has your animation applied to it. Then you can set the colour on the controllers view.